# Boolean following pointer and number elements

Tags: matlab, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use boolean flags to determine which data needs to be loaded. For example, I have 5 data sets and I ordered them by energy with a pointer which is in an array in MATLAB. I have to connect 2 data sets which have the following order: `order =[5 2 3 4 1]`
That means if I have to use 1 data set the boolean will be

```
b= [ 0 0 0 0 1] % the fifth data set will de loaded 

Power_load_1 = calculalation_X *b=0
to
Power_load_4 = calculalation_X *b=0
Power_load_5 = calculalation_X *b= a result
```

If 2 data sets must be loaded:

```
b= [ 0 1 0 0 1]

Power_load_1 = calculalation_X *b=0
Power_load_2 = calculalation_X *b= a result
Power_load_3 and 4 = calculalation_X *b=0
Power_load_5 = calculalation_X *b= a result
```

I tried to use `b=true(order(1,1:nbr_load))`, but this results in

```
5×2 logical array
    
b =
1   1
1   1
1   1
1   1
1   1
```

it seeems the origin of the problem is  this

```
order(1,1:nbr_load)

ans =

     5     2
```

It is an instruction to form 5 lines to 2 columns, which I do not want

How can I generate my booleans?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple loop over `order` into a logical array `b`, using `1:ii` to select the relevant elements from `order`:

```
order =[5 2 3 4 1];
b = zeros(numel(order),max(order), 'logical');  % Initliase output
for ii = 1:numel(order)
    b(ii,order(1:ii)) = 1;
end
b

b =

     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you for you time and correction of my initial post I will go with  b = zeros(1,5, 'logical');  % Initliase output
>> b(1,order(1:2)) = 1; i will use it for the initialisation. I will use this line each time when i will renew my energy board